# What I wrote to html doesn't register?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on the Angular hotel project. There is a menu button on the main page and there are 2 options. Option 2 goes to the reservation detail page. The codes that I wrote in the html part of this component are not registered. I see the main article every time I run it (reservationdetail works!). How can I fix this.

.hotel-component-html

```
<button id="btnMenu" class="btn btn-warning" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Reservations 
Details</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
<button mat-menu-item (click)="search2()">Price Search</button>
<button mat-menu-item (click)="navigate()">Reservations List</button>
</mat-menu>
```

.hotel-component-ts

```
navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(["reservationdetail"]);
}
```

.reservationdetail-component-html

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

.app-routing-module-ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'hotel', component: HotelComponent },
{ path: 'rezervazyon', component: RezervasyonComponent },
{ path: 'reservationdetail', component: ReservationdetailComponent },
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "hotel" }
];
```

.app-component-html

```
 <div class='container-fluid'>
 <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the route config?

Comment: sorry i don't understand exactly what you are asking for your router file?

Comment: @enesturan Yes. Your `app-routing.module.ts` file

Comment: I edited the code. There is no problem with the route event, I can go to the component, but html does not work.

Comment: Ok so where is the router-outlet in the html? I mean, where the new component should be placed?

Comment: It seems like your code is going to `**` path, that is why it is loading `HotelComponent`... Am I correct?

Comment: I rearranged the code and added the part that is router-outlet

Comment: No @kenny. My code goes to the backup detail page. The router works properly, but the new codes I write in html don't work never. Continuously writes reservation detail works!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it to /reservationdetail as it is at same level as hotel, you need to navigate from root by using /

```
navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(["/reservationdetail"]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Route is working properly. My problem is that the code I wrote in html is not registered, it always writes reservationdetail works.

Comment: @enesturan can you create a small reproducible example? it will be easier to find why that might be happening

Comment: What do you want a repeatable sample? I do not fully understand

Comment: you can try to create a small example here https://stackblitz.com/

with a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can just use a `routerLink` directive:

```
<button mat-menu-item routerLink="/reservationdetail">Reservations List</button>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Route is working properly. My problem is that the code I wrote in html is not registered, it always writes reservationdetail works.

Comment: probably need to show the detail component then, not just the html, but the controller code

Comment: I did not write a separate controller for this component. I wrote the hotel for the reservation but I did not write for it. Here I will only show the recorded data.

Comment: You need to write a controller for every component.

Answer (score 0):

If you keeps seeing the "reservation detail works!" even you have changed the content of the html file, this is a known bug of Angular `ng serve`. Just restart the dev server and it will be fine.